# ¿Como puedo parsear un String XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsear, sax

estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android, mi error es el siguiente, desde la Aplicación, envío un parámetro a una consulta, de un php, dentro de este php, cuando hace la consulta, genera una respuesta de manera estructurando un XML.(Adjunto el php para que veáis como lo tengo hecho).

```
    <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.es", "u126083979_admin", "123456", "u126083979_lugar");
     if(isset($_POST['nombre']))
     {
      $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
      $query1 = "SELECT * FROM Sitio WHERE Nombre = '".$nombre."'";
       if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query1))
       {
             echo "<Sitios>";
             while($Sitio = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
             {
              echo "<Sitio>";
              echo "<Nombre>" . $Sitio['Nombre'] . "</Nombre>";
              echo "<ImagenPrin>" . $Sitio['ImagenPrin'] . "</ImagenPrin>";
              echo "</Sitio>";
             }
             echo "</Sitios>";
             mysqli_free_result($result);

       }
       else
       {
         echo "ERROR: $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
       }
     }
?>
```

Partiendo de que mi php me dé la respuesta en forma de xml, en la clase leo, esta respuesta de la siguiente manera.

```
int response_code = conexion.getResponseCode();

                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    // Lee los datos enviados desde el php
                    InputStream input = conexion.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    String vble="";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                        vble=vble+line;                       
                    }
```

Ahora bien, según tengo entendido, la respuesta está guardada en la Variable String ***vble***, en estos momentos, y lo que yo quiero ahora mismo es parsear la variable. Yo lo tengo de la siguiente manera.

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
                    SaxHandlerSitio handler = new SaxHandlerSitio();
                    saxParser.parse(vble, handler);
```

No entiendo porque no se me parsea, por ultimo añado mi clase de parseo mediante SAXHANDLER.

```
public class SaxHandlerSitio extends DefaultHandler{
    private List<Sitio> sitios;
    private Sitio sitioAc;
    private StringBuilder sbText;
    public Boolean parsingError = false;



    public List<Sitio> getSitios(){
        return sitios;
    }


    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {

        super.startDocument();

        sitios = new ArrayList<Sitio>();
        sbText = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        super.startElement(uri, localName, name, attributes);

        if (localName.equals("Sitio")) {
            sitioAc = new Sitio(name, 0,0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        super.characters(ch, start, length);

        if (this.sitioAc != null)
            sbText.append(ch, start, length);
    }


    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {

        super.endElement(uri, localName, name);
        double value;
        int valor = 0;
        if (this.sitioAc != null) {

            if (localName.equals("Nombre")) {
                sitioAc.setNombre(sbText.toString().trim());
            }
            else if (localName.equals("Latitud")) {
                value = Double.parseDouble(sbText.toString().trim());
                sitioAc.setLatitud(value);
            }
            else if (localName.equals("Longitud")) {
                value = Double.parseDouble(sbText.toString().trim());
                sitioAc.setLongitud(value);
            }
            else if (localName.equals("ImagenPrin")) {
                sitioAc.setImagen(sbText.toString().trim());
            }
            else if (localName.equals("Sitio")) {
                sitios.add(sitioAc);
            }
            sbText.setLength(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Estos son los errores que me salen

```
04-18 18:04:45.530 12331-20851/com.adilosa94.theturistllion W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Couldn't open <Sitios><Sitio><Nombre>Basílica de San Isidoro</Nombre><ImagenPrin>http://theturistllion.hol.es/upload/Imagenes/Sitios%20Principal/san_isidoro.jpg</ImagenPrin></Sitio></Sitios>
    04-18 18:04:45.533 12331-20851/com.adilosa94.theturistllion W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: <Sitios><Sitio><Nombre>Basílica de San Isidoro</Nombre><ImagenPrin>http://theturistllion.hol.es/upload/Imagenes/Sitios%20Principal/san_isidoro.jpg</ImagenPrin></Sitio></Sitios>
```

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu pregunta con los detalles específicos del error que obtienes y por favor evita usar mayúsculas. No conozco java, pero puedes guiarte con esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8408730/4092887) o puedes consultar `java parse xml string`.

Answer (score 1):

El error te dice que ha intentado abrir como URI (o sea URL) lo que en realidad es el contenido del XML.

Si vamos al siempre útil Javadoc, vemos que de [SAXParser.parse(String, DefaultHandler)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler)) dice que el primer parámetro es la URI de donde obtener el XML a parsear.

Así pues, debería bastar con hacer

```
 saxParser.parse(laUrlDeMiXml, handler);
```

y eliminar todo el método de obtener el String a través de la conexión.

Si por cualquier motivo (autenticación, por mayor control/log, etc.) quieres seguir abriendo la conexión/descargando el XML como String, deberías usar algún otro de los métodos `parse` existentes; por ejemplo

```
saxParser.parse(connection.getInputStream(), handler);
```

o

```
saxParser.parse(new InputSource(vble), handler);
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que me quieres decir, lo unico yo se hacerlo, si que en el php, pida un parametro a la consulta. Lo que no se es como dando un parametro a la consulta hacer el parseo es decir hasta que la consulta no recibe ese parametro no crear el xml, ¿entonces meto igualmente la url?

Comment: Tu comentario no está nada claro. En todo caso los parámetros pasados por GET son parte de la URI/URL; si lo quieres pasar por POST puedes hacer la conexión y descarga del XML fuera del parser (tal como lo pones en tu pregunta) y luego usar el segundo ejemplo que pongo.